# Within While Loop how to execute "Use [database name] Go"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I need to shrink the log file for every database weekly. 
I am writing a while loop query to loop each database. but i don't think it is allowed to do the following:

```
declare @database_id int
declare @database varchar(255)
declare @log varchar(255)
declare @cmd varchar(500)

while (select count(*) from #LogFiles where processed = 0) > 0
begin 

    set @database_id = (select min(database_id) from #LogFiles where processed = 0)
    set @database = (select name from #LogFiles where database_id = @database_id and [type] = 0)
    set @log = (select name from #LogFiles where database_id = @database_id and [type] = 1)

    select @database, @log

        set @cmd = 'Use ' + @Database
        exec(@cmd)

    set @cmd = 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (' + @log + ');'

    exec(@cmd)

    update #LogFiles 
    set processed = 1
    where database_id = @database_id

end
```

Or is there another way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is after "use[database]" it needs a "Go", and it is not allowed to use "go" within a loop

Comment: Try doing it all at once: `'use ' + @database + ' dbcc shrinkfile (' + @log + ')'`

Comment: Ugh - why are you repeatedly shrinking all of your log files? What version is this, what recovery model are you using, and if full, why aren't you performing log backups so that the log size manages itself? What are you going to do with all this free space you free up temporarily?

Comment: Also, can you show the query you use to populate #LogFiles? Even if this were a good idea, there are much more efficient ways to do this than a #temp table and a while loop.

Comment: Why are you shrinking your logfiles? Unless you've had massive, massive write operations on every, single, database on the server, your databases are demonstrating a need to have log files of this size. You're just setting yourself up for the overhead of log file growths in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your concerns. We have a limited server space, the log files usually go to 10GB+ for some projects that we deal with. We need to free those spaces. #logfiles has all the database names from system that i need to execute.

Comment: @AaronBertrand what are those much more efficient ways?

Comment: Can you let us know how you populate #LogFiles please?

Comment: sure, it's from sys.master_files table

Comment: @Kric well I figured that, but what query did you use? How did you leave out system databases or databases that you *don't* want to shrink?

Comment: If you're not backing up your log files, you should change all user databases to SIMPLE recovery model, this will minimise the growth of log files.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank again Aaron. I exclude all the system databases in that temp table.

Comment: @Nathan yes, i set all the databases' recovery model as SIMPLE. but but but, still get very large log files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was mentioned in multiple comments, this really, really, REALLY isn't a good idea. Shrinking these files just so they can grow again next week is wasted effort and, since log file autogrow events can't take advantage of instant file initialization (since, unlike data file allocations, log file allocations really have to be zeroed out before use), this can really impact end user performance in ways that you can't predict or control.

That said, ditch the #temp table and <s>cursor</s> while loop. Technically this still uses a loop to concatenate but it's so much easier to set up and look at.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX); SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
  USE ' + QUOTENAME(db) + ';
  PRINT DB_NAME();
  CHECKPOINT; -- since we now know it is simple recovery
  DBCC SHRINKFILE(' + QUOTENAME(f) + ') WITH NO_INFOMSGS;'
FROM
(
  SELECT DB_NAME(database_id), name
   FROM sys.master_files
   WHERE database_id > 4 AND [type] = 1
   -- AND LOWER(name) NOT IN (N'reportserver', N'reportservertempdb')
) AS x(db, f);

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Check out the `PRINT` output. When you're satisfied it's going to do what you think, uncomment the `EXEC` and run it again.

Comment: Also, for this to even work he'll have to actually backup the logs.

Comment: @swasheck true, if he's in full. I was going to get into that but the methods for doing so depend on recovery model (which we don't know) and version (which we also don't know).

Comment: gotcha. i figured that was the case - and you know what they say about too much rope :D

Comment: @swasheck I'll confess part of it is I didn't want to make it too easy for precisely that reason. :-)

Comment: I think you could just `PRINT DB_NAME();` *after* the `USE`, no?

Comment: @AndriyM sure. I'm not typically building commands that require explicit database context, so I didn't 't think of it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks Aaron. The version is SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise. The server we use is not a back-end database connecting to a front UI software or anything. We use it for data migration.

Comment: I still have a hard time to understand why the log files are that important as i have a weekly run maintenance plan to get full backups.

Comment: @Kric because if you shrink the log file and then they have to grow because some user started a big transaction, that user has to ***sit and wait*** while the log file grows again. What did you gain by shrinking the file ***temporarily***? Did you rent out the space to someone else and then evict them?

Comment: @AaronBertrand that's why we want to make this as a stored proc, after running the full backup, run this code again. Hmm I don't quite understand what do you mean by "that user has to sit and wait while the log file grows again"?

Comment: @Kric did you read my answer? e.g. the part about instant file initialization? When a log file needs to grow, SQL Server asks the operating system to expand the file. While it does this, all transactions have to stop and wait, while SQL Server writes zeros throughout the newly expanded portion of the log file. If you have bad default settings like 10% autogrow, this takes longer and longer every time. And if you have transactions that require more space than the autogrow setting allocates, you have to wait for this process to happen multiple times.

Comment: @AaronBertrand we have a limited server space. (around 300G), we have a couple of big ones sitting in there (60G+) and the log files usually go above 10G+. so we desperately want to clean some space.

Comment: @Kric you need to find out why your log files are exceeding the space you have allocated (in simple recovery they should not be growing beyond what they need), or you need to allocate more space to accommodate them. This is an extremely wasteful and expensive operation to repeat every single week. I get that you need to do what you need to do, but then you either fix it or don't say things like "I don't understand why the log files are important." I've explained in several ways why they are, and you can act on that, or don't. *shrug*

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for your patience. i know it's hard for you to explain those kind of things to a newbie like me. I get it. :D